# My jquery click isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-frontend

I am making a website and I included jQuery.
When I use click events, it isn't working.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="text-center">Pomodoro Clock</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="container">

    <div id="counter-main">
      <h1>Session Time</h1>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="plusCounterMain">-</a>
      <h2 id="timerMain">5</h2>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="minusCounterMain">+</a>
    </div>
    <div id="resetDiv">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="resetMain">Reset</a>
    </div>

    <div id="break-main">
      <h1>Session Time</h1>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="plusBreakMain">-</a>
      <h2 id="breakCount">5</h2>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="minusBreakMain">+</a>
    </div>
    <div id="startDiv">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start</button>          
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.0"></script>
</body>
```

Here is my JavaScript(jQuery) code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var timer_main = $("#timerMain");
  var break_count = $("#breakCount");

  var count = parseInt(timer_main.html());
  var break = parseInt(break_count.html());

  $("plusCounterMain").click(function(){
    count +=5;
    console.log(count.toString());
    timer_main.text(count.toString());
  });

  $("#start").click(function{
    var counter = setInterval(timer,1000);

    function timer() {
      count -=1;
      if (count === 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
      $("#timerMain").text(count.toString());
    }
  });
});
```

I have no idea where I went wrong.
I was trying to make a pomodoro clock, so I used the setInterval function to execute code every second.

Where have I went wrong?

Comment: You missed `#` in `$("plusCounterMain")`

Comment: I've made the changes. It still doesnt work

Comment: @SriramR see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors 1. break is a reserved word,2. you forgot the () in the #start click event function,3. the # in the plusCounterMain id

```js
  var timer_main = $("#timerMain");
  var break_count = $("#breakCount");


  var count = parseInt(timer_main.html());
  var breaked = parseInt(break_count.html());

  $("#plusCounterMain").click(function() {
    count += 5;
    console.log(count.toString());
    timer_main.text(count.toString());
  });


  $("#start").click(function (){
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer() {
      count -= 1;
      if (count === 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
      $("#timerMain").text(count.toString());
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1 class="text-center">Pomodoro Clock</h1>
</header>

<section class="container">

  <div id="counter-main">
    <h1>Session Time</h1>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="plusCounterMain">-</a>
    <h2 id="timerMain">5</h2>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="minusCounterMain">+</a>
  </div>
  <div id="resetDiv"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="resetMain">Reset</a></div>

  <div id="break-main">
    <h1>Session Time</h1>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="plusBreakMain">-</a>
    <h2 id="breakCount">5</h2>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="minusBreakMain">+</a>
  </div>
  <div id="startDiv"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start</button>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- jQuery library -->
```

Note: you should use classes if your implementation has multiple instances

Comment: yeah I fixed it. There was some error in the jquery file I downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Id should be prefix with #. The main issue is you have given variable name as break. This is keyword in JS. I have changed it. Please check below code.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
var timer_main = $("#timerMain");
var break_count = $("#breakCount");


var count = parseInt(timer_main.html());
var breakCount = parseInt(break_count.html());

$("#plusCounterMain").click(function(){
    count +=5;
    console.log(count.toString());
    timer_main.text(count.toString());
});


$("#start").click(function(){
    var counter = setInterval(timer,1000);

    function timer() {
        count -=1;
        if (count === 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
        $("#timerMain").text(count.toString());
    }

}); });
```

Comment: Check updated code now.. You have missed function parentheses in start click

Answer (score 0):

Check your click events in console with following approach

```
$(document).on('click','#plusCounterMain',function(){
       console.log('In plusCounterMain');
});

$(document).on('click','#start',function(){
       console.log('In start');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var timer_main = $("#timerMain");
var break_count = $("#breakCount");


var count = parseInt(timer_main.html());
/*var break = parseInt(break_count.html()); */

$("#plusCounterMain").click(function(){
    count +=5;
    console.log(count.toString());
    timer_main.text(count.toString());
});

$("#start").click(function(){
    var counter = setInterval(timer,1000);

    function timer() {
        count -=1;
        if (count === 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
        $("#timerMain").text(count.toString());
    }
});
```

});

Comment: can you explain what you did here?

Comment: function(), You do not give ().    var break = parseInt(break_count.html()); this is not found ! and I just active click event.

Comment: use a little more words and put it in the answer not in a comment, your answer has no value and the code is similar to my code

Comment: I just Cheange Your Problem !